# how to multiply from the starting of index [ 0 ]. Here it is taking only 4 values .

Tags: javascript

When I try to execute this it takes index from [1] position but not zero. How to take from zero.

```
 function mul(){
 var temp = 1;
 for (i=1 ; i < arguments.length; i++){
  temp = temp * arguments[i];
  }
  return temp;
  }

   var list = mul(2,2,2,2,2);
  alert(list);
```

Comment: Check the line 3 of your code.

Comment: Also, enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode); `i` isn’t declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because var i is set to 1. arguments is an array-like object and it also start from 0 index. In your case your are starting from 1st index.

```js
function mul() {
  var temp = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    temp = temp * arguments[i];
  }
  return temp;
}

var list = mul(2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
console.log(list);
```

According to [**airbnb**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions) style it is better to use rest syntax instead of arguments object. Beside `i` in the for loop has not defined with `var` keyword. In that case it will be global variable & will be accessible from other function. So defining a variable with `var` keyword will bound its scope to current function only. You can also explore `let`

```js
function mul(...args) {
  var temp = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    temp = temp * args[i];
  }
  return temp;
}

var list = mul(2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: I know it's irrelevant but I think it could be helpful to mention how `var i = 0` is better than just `i = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The line 3 `for` loop:

```
for (i=0 ; i < arguments.length; i++){...
```

Comment: An explanation is required. Just "change it to this" is not the best way to answer.